# Order Tables Schema Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, database-design, schema

I have two tables Order_Primary and Order_Complete the problem is when I want to generate the bill there could be multiple products in the bill in the Order_Primary table, so it will generate OrderId for each single product though they are from the same bill, now how should I associate all these OrderId in Order_Complete table as there will be multiple OrderIds for the same product but there has to be only one BillNo

Order_Primary

> OrderId (Primary Key)
>   ProductId (Foreign Key)
>   CategoryId (Foreign Key)
>   Quantity 
>   Cost 
>   EmployeeId (Foreign Key)

Order_Complete

> BillNo (Primary Key)
>   OrderId (Foreign Key)
>   Date

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To get the desired result you have to change your Data-Structure to something like this:

Product_Group (add a new table)

```
ProductId (Foreign Key)
ProductGroupId
ProductGroupId+ProductId (Primary Key)
```

Order_Primary

```
OrderId (Primary Key)
ProductGroupId 
^(Now here with a ProductGroupId you will get a list of products(Multiple))
CategoryId (Foreign Key)
Quantity 
Cost 
EmployeeId (Foreign Key)
```

Order_Complete

```
BillNo (Primary Key)
OrderId (Foreign Key)
Date
```